# Octave database connection

Tags: sql, database, octave

Does anyone know how to connect to an ODBC database in Octave? The database package doesn't seem to install properly. I found this bug here:

http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?30090

Is there any other method? I am actually trying to connect to SQL Server and am using Windows 7 (not linux unfortunately, at my work place!).

If not, are there any other matlab type programming environments out there that anyone would recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A looong time ago I wrote a connector for [Octave](http://www.octave.org) to [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org) (which is still on its webpage [here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/octave-pg.html)).  Maybe you could use that a starting point?

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately I don't have the time to go and write my own connector. Seems pretty basic functionality, but I guess this is what using an open source free alternative is about that doesn't have a massive following. I think I'm just going to export the data to a CSV then import that way into Octave.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from a reply by Martin Helm to the [same question on the Octave forum](https://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Octave-and-databases-td2402806.html) which suggests using Java plus JDBC. -

> Look at the java bindings in the octave java package (octave-forge), it is
> maintained and it works. Java is very strong and easy for database handling.
> Use that and jdbc driver for mysql to connect to mysql (or with the
> appropriate jdbc driver everything else which you can imagine). That is what I
> do when using db queries from octave. Much easier and less indirect than
> invoking scripts and parsing output from databse queries.
>
> As far as I remeber the database package is somehow broken (at least I never
> was able to use it).

I also have this problem and will be giving this a try.